# Is there a foolproof way to give the system enough time to delete a folder before running copytree

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I have some directories that I need to update I was using the following code

```
for newdir in newdirs:
    olddir = newdir.replace('h:\\','G:\\').replace('_academic','')
    shutil.rmtree(newdir)
    shutil.copytree(olddir,newdir)
```

I would occasionally get an error

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'h:\\mydir\\sub1\\sub2\\sub3\\sub4\\sub5'
```

since the error would not happen on the previous directories I decided that the cause must be some access conflict - too little time was taking place between the rmtree call and copytree so I modified the code to waste some time

```
for newdir in newdirs:
    olddir = newdir.replace('h:\\','G:\\').replace('_academic','')
    shutil.rmtree(newdir)
    for item in range(0,20,1):
        pass
    shutil.copytree(olddir,newdir)
```

This made the error go away and the old directory was copied to the new location.

I don't like this because it seems pretty ramshackle - even for me.

1. Am I wrong about the cause of the error (conflict)
2. Is there a better way to make sure the system has enough time to complete the rmtree operation before we begin the copytree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the error goes away when you wait, you're probably not wrong about the cause. So following up on the idea of waiting, but waiting with purpose, this might be *ever so slightly* better:

```
for newdir in newdirs:
    olddir = newdir.replace('h:\\','G:\\').replace('_academic','')
    shutil.rmtree(newdir)
    while os.path.exists(newdir): # check if it exists
        pass
    shutil.copytree(olddir,newdir)
```

Should some strange error occur preventing the directory from being removed but not raising an exception, the `while` loop could theoretically go forever, but I find that highly unlikely.

I'm not proud of this solution **at all**, but barring new knowledge, this should be a little more fool-proof than an arbitrary delay.

Comment: I like this because you are exactly right, waiting with a purpose instead of some random count.  Thanks for the suggestion.